# Only base in definition of compactness - do we need AC?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness, axiom-of-choice

This is the usual definition of a [compact space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space): A topological space is compact iff every open cover has a finite subcover.

It is possible to consider only covers by sets from a fixed [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) $\mathcal B$ instead of arbitrary cover. So we have the following result:

**Claim.** Let $\mathcal B$ be a base for $X$. Let $X$ be a space such that every open cover *with sets from $\mathcal B$* has a finite subcover. Then $X$ is compact.

The same claim is true also for a [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase). In this case it is known as [Alexander subbase theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_subbase_theorem). The usual proof uses Zorn's Lemma and it cannot be proven in ZF alone. It is equivalent to the [Boolean prime ideal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem#The_ultrafilter_lemma) and the Ultrafilter lemma.<sup>1</sup>

If we only work with bases, the proof of the above claim is much more straightforward - still it uses Axiom of Choice:

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal U$ by any open cover of $X$. Let us take the set $\mathcal B'=\{B\in\mathcal B; (\exists U\in\mathcal U) B\subseteq U\}$, i.e., the set consisting of all basic set which lie entirely inside some set from the original open cover. The set $\mathcal B'$ is an open cover of $X$. (Indeed, for every $x\in X$ there is some $U\in\mathcal U$ such that $x\in U$. And, by the definition of base, there exists $B\in\mathcal B$ with $x\in B\subseteq U$.)

Since $\mathcal B'\subseteq\mathcal B$, there is an open subcover $\{B_1,\dots,B_n\}$ of $\mathcal B'$. Now for each $B_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ we can *choose* some $U_i\in\mathcal U$ such that $B_i\subseteq U_i$. The set $\{U_1,\dots,U_n\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal U$. Q.E.D

**Question.** Can the above claim be shown in ZF?

<sup>1</sup>I can add another reference if I find it, but at least this is claimed in some posts on this site, such as: [Ultrafilter Lemma and Alexander subbase theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963068) and [What is Alexander subbase theorem equivalent to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305349)

Comment: You are making finitely many choices. This can be done in ZF without AC.

Comment: @Wojowu This is quite embarrassing. (I have overcomplicated things and missed the simple solution.) You might expand your comment and post it an answer. (Possibly you could include a link to a post about finite AC, such as: [Do We Need the Axiom of Choice for Finite Sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132717)) Unless somebody posts something more relevant than this simple observation, I'll be happy to accept your answer. (And I'll try to reformulate [the original version of my Question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3440622/2) so that it can be made into a separate post.

Comment: @Wojowu and MSleziak So the question is solved, and my comment relates to a different question, or rather it states a version of the above question for which the proof might not be so obvious. Let $\mathcal B$ be a base for a space $X$. Call $X$ $\mathcal B$-Lindelof if every subcover of $\mathcal B$ has a countable subcover. Is a $\mathcal B$-Lindelof space Lindelof? Yes, under countable choice. A variation, call $X$ base-Lindelof if it is $\mathcal B$-Lindelof for some base $\mathcal B$ with $\mathcal B=w(X)$. Also,generalize to arbitrary Lindelof degree $l(X)$. Why would it be interesting?

Comment: @Mirko Re: *Why is it interesting?* The standard proofs of the result about bases is much simpler than the standard proof for Alexander subbase theorem. Since it is known that the latter cannot be proved in ZF, the question whether the easier result can be shown in ZF seemed interesting to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof for basic covers can be written choiceless, as you did:

$\mathcal{B}'=\{B \in \mathcal{B}: \exists U \in \mathcal{U}: B \subseteq U\}$ is a well-defined family of sets (no choice needed).

It is a cover of $X$ because $\mathcal{U}$ is and $\mathcal{B}$ is a base:
let $X \in X$. For some $U_x \in \mathcal{U}$ we have $x \in U_x$. There is a basic $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq U_x$. Now the existence of $U_x$ "witnesses" that $B_x \in \mathcal{B}'$ and that set contains $x$. As $x$ was arbitrary, $\mathcal{B}'$ is a cover of $X$ by base elements.

By assumption, this has a finite subcover $\{B_1,\ldots, B_n\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}'$, for each $1 \le i\le n$ pick a "witnessing" $U_i \in \mathcal{U}$ with $B_i \subseteq U_i$ (we don't need AC for **finitely many** choices (see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/132723/4280)). And the larger $U_i$ of course also form a cover of $X$ and are the required subcover of $\mathcal{U}$.

Another proof approach *would* use choice: Suppose $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover. For each $x$ pick $U_x$ in the cover and a base element $B_x$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq U_x$. The $\{B_x: x \in X\}$ form a cover of $X$ "by construction", so finitely many, say, $B_{x_1},\ldots, B_{x_n}$ cover $X$ and $\{U_{x_1}, \ldots, U_{x_n}\}$ is then a finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}$. Quick, easy but heavy on choice (which we don't really need for this implication, as we saw above). So the proof set-up matters. Very often, with smarter definitions, we can avoid some uses of AC. Most topologists "don't care", and arguments of the latter type are very common.

For the subbase version (Alexander's subbase lemma), we **do** essentially need a form of choice: the standard reference book *Consequences of the axiom of choice* mentions it under subtype [14]: equivalent to the Boolean prime ideal theorem and also the theorem that any product of compact Hausdorff spaces is compact. (so "almost" full AC IMHO).

Comment: I will just point out that Tychonoff theorem for *arbitrary* spaces is equivalent to AC. If we work with Hausdorff spaces only, we get a result equivalent to Boolean prime ideal theorem or ultrafilter lemma. This is mentioned, for example, in Herrlich's *Axiom of Choice* as Theorem 4.68 and Theorem 4.70, [page 86](https://books.google.com/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC&pg=PA86). (I'm not sure, perhaps this is what you meant by *almost* full AC.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Exactly, full Tychonoff is AC, ASL is BPI is Tychonoff in $\texttt{Haus}$, so "almost" full AC. (it's mostly used for Hausdorff spaces anyway).

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Just a typo: should be "let $x \in X$" (lowercase $x$) in the 3rd line.